# Using Stack2RSS, why can I get feeds for some SE sites and not others?

Tags: support, rss

I can use Stack2RSS to easily get RSS feeds of some StackExchange sites but not others:

The pattern if I understand the API is http://stack2rss.stackexchange.com/{SiteName}/questions

Substituting the following for {SiteName} all work

- StackOverflow
- ServerFault
- SuperUser

Substituting the following for {SiteName} all fail to return a feed:

- Bicycles
- English
- Programmers
- Webmasters

Comment: Weird problem. Although fixable by adding full name of the sites `bicycles.stackexchange.com`?

Comment: True - it looks like if you replace {SiteName} with bicycles.stackexchange.com rather than just bicycles it does work. I wonder if there is an "alias" of some kind on the SE sites that allows the others to work.

Comment: same for physics.